# Recursive code to create small shift dictionary

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following attempt at a recursive function to create a shift table within a dictionary:

```
def createShiftTable(alphabet,T,shiftT):
    if not T:
        for char in alphabet:
            shiftT[char] = len(T)+1
        return shiftT
    else:
        return createShiftTable(alphabet,T[1:],shiftT)
        shiftT[T[0]] = len(T) 


al=['a','b','c','d']
T = "aaabbdddaaba"
print(createShiftTable(al,T,{}))
```

This is returning `{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 1}`
I'd like it to return `{'a': 1, 'c': 13, 'b': 2, 'd': 5}`

Non-recursively the following works ok but how do I get the above recursive function working?

```
def createShiftTableX(alphabet,T):
    shiftT={}
    for char in al:
        shiftT[char] = len(T)+1   
    for i in range(len(T)):
        shiftT[T[i]] = len(T)-i    

    return shiftT

al=['a','b','c','d']
T = "aaabbdddaaba"
print(createShiftTableX(al,T))
```

Comment: `shiftT[T[0]] = len(T)`  is unreachable, BTW

Comment: @akaRem like I say in the question "I have the following attempt " - it is possible to put code after a recursive call: can you explain why this is unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
def createShiftTableX(alphabet, T):
    l = len(T)
    for c in alphabet:
        i = T.find(c)
        if i<0:
            yield l
        else:
            yield i+1

al=['a','b','c','d']
T = "aaabbdddaaba"
print(list(createShiftTableX(al,T)))
```

Comment: +1 ok - thanks but I'm aiming to keep things recursive....is the operator `yield` recursive?

Comment: No, yield means that function becomes generator. Check docs for that.

Comment: @whytheq recursive is not necessary for this job

Comment: ...recursion is part of the point of the question: I'm trying to get comfortable with recursive functions in Python.

Comment: @whytheq do you like to dig with fork or showel? use appropriate tools! Plus recursion in python does not have tail optimization.

Comment: very true...but when leaning to use a fork or shovel it's not always so important.

Answer (score -1):

You should run this in a debugger or put in some logging or print statements to see what it is actually doing.

Comment: it is short enough so that with experience I will be able to debug small recursive scripts like this by eye ...but I'm still just getting a feel for recursive functions

Comment: that's obvious: function searches index of char. Subcalls have slice as arg, so the resulting index is shifted.

Comment: "that's obvious" ...what is (!). Heikka's answer or my comment?